# Assemble and deploy ATG 11 module issue

Tags: oracle, atg, commerce

I have created a new atg module using eclipse plugin. I use CIM to assemble and deploy the project, it works well but when i created a custom droplet, the src folder and the config folder didn't assemble, the generated EAR contains only the JSPs and atg required libraries.

Project structure

http://postimg.org/image/98pk5o84n/

Manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0  
ATG-Config-Path: config/  
ATG-Required: DAS DPS DSS   
ATG-J2EE: j2ee-apps/EShop-ee.ear  
ATG-EAR-Module: j2ee-apps/EShop-ee.ear  
ATG-Class-Path: lib/
```

Comment: After building the module, does config/ and lib/ contain the .class and .properties files that you say should be there?  What does your runAssembler output look like?

Answer (score 1):

1. As I see lib folder is empty. Please double check that this folder contains your compiled custom droplet.
2. The src folder will not be assembled into target ear.
3. As for the config folder - it depends on how you use runAssembler script.

runAssembler has 3 modes:

1. -run-in-place. Target ear file contains only web apps and their content (JSPs, static content). Config files and classes are used from platform installation folder.
2. Default mode. Target ear file contains web apps together with all libraries and classes. Config files are used from platform installation folder.
3. -standalone. Target ear file contains web apps, classes and config files. You can find config files in: app.ear\atg_bootstrap.war\WEB-INF\ATG-INF\

Hope this helps.